# Does a Wizard gain treasures from a charmed monster AND flee a second monster during the same combat?

Tags: munchkin

During a combat, I was first fighting a monster of level 6, that I could easily beat. Then, a player added a monster to the combat of level 18, that I couldn't successfully beat. So, as a Wizard, I was able to charm the highest monster, so he leaves his treasures in the room.

The question is; **do I directly gain the left treasures within my hands after charming the monster, as stated in the Wizard card ?**

However, I ended fleeing the entire combat. Do I gain the treasures left in the room still?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**. From the [FAQ](https://munchkin.game/gameplay/faq/):

> ...if you use an ability to make one monster disappear, you cannot claim
> levels and/or Treasures for beating it (depending on the method used)
> unless you can then kill or defeat all the remaining monsters. You
> cannot, for instance, use your Wizard to charm one monster and take
> its Treasures before fighting the rest. Combat isn't over until the
> WHOLE combat is over.

Comment: I didn't know this website. Thank you for your answer!